# Print Twig variable x times based upon randomized range

Tags: php, twig, timber

I am using Twig and Timber for a WordPress project. I have the following loop in my template that prints my custom post type titles into a HTML structure.

```
{% for company in companies %}

  {% set dot = "<div class='company-dot'></div>" %}
  {% set range = range(10, 20) %}

  {{dot}}
  {{random(range)}}

  <div class="company">
    <div class="company-dot dot-active"></div>
    <p class="dot-caption">{{ company.title }}</p>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

I would like to print my `{{dot}}` variable x amount of times based upon the number that is generated by `{{random(range)}}`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to iterate `random(range)` times with a `for` loop:

```
{% for i in 0..random(range(10, 20)) %}
    {{ dot }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: or if you have a variable you could do                                                                                  {% for i in range(1, quantity) %}
    {{ dot }}
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know Twig but my guess is that you could to the following:

```
{% for i in random(range) %}
  {{dot}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to use `range`, just use it again :

```
 {% set dots_count = random(range) %}
 {% for dot_index in range(1,dots_count) %}
    {{dot}}
 {% endfor %}

 {{dots_count}}
```

Here is a fiddle : https://twigfiddle.com/ko595z